# Reference for the Brown representability theorem in the case of locally presentable (∞,1)-categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, representable-functors

Various generalizations of the Brown representability theorem
found in the literature identify additional conditions one can impose on a category $C$ so that functors $\def\op{{\sf op}}\def\Set{{\sf Set}} C^\op→\Set$ preseving small products and [weak pullbacks](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit) are representable.
For example, there are versions for homotopy categories of model categories (Theorem 24 in [Jardine](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/JardineBrownrep.pdf)) and quasicategories (Lurie, Theorem 1.4.1.2 in [Higher Algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf)).  There is also a version for the special case of triangulated categories ([Neeman](https://doi.org/10.1090/s0894-0347-96-00174-9), Theorem 3.1).  All these formulations require $C$ to be compactly generated in the appropriate sense (there are multiple inequivalent definitions found in the literature).

Since more than one statement can be found in the literature,
here is the precise version I am interested in (Theorem 1.4.1.2 in Higher Algebra): if $C$ is a locally presentable (∞,1)-category with a set of compact objects that admit a cogroup structure in $\def\Ho{{\sf Ho}}\Ho(C)$ and generate $C$ under homotopy colimits, then a functor $F\colon \Ho(C)^\op→\Set$ is representable if and only if it preserves small products and weak pullbacks.

Looking at the proofs, it appears to me that the theorem should continue to hold in the case of locally α-presentable (∞,1)-categories (not necessarily compactly generated)
for any regular cardinal α, provided the functor $F$
satisfies one additional condition: for any α-filtered category $I$ (taking $I$ to be an ordinal should suffice)
and any diagram $D\colon I→C$,
the induced map $\def\colim{\mathop{\rm colim}} F(\colim D) → \lim F∘D$ should be a surjective map of sets.
That is, $F$ should send α-filtered (∞,1)-colimits in $C$ to weak α-cofiltered limits.
I haven't checked all the details carefully, but if this is the case, is this written up anywhere?

**What is a citeable reference for the Brown representability theorem in the case of locally presentable (∞,1)-categories?**

A question of secondary importance is whether one can give a simple counterexample that shows the above condition involving α-filtered (co)limits to be necessary.
The specific (∞,1)-category $C$ that I am interested in is the category of (∞,1)-sheaves of spectra (or pointed spaces) on the site of smooth manifolds.
This (∞,1)-category is not compactly generated.

Comment: There are two theorems in Brown's paper which are known as Brown representability theorem. The first one holds often and the second one seldom. Let's stick to the first one. Neeman proved in his book about triangulated categories that well generated triangulated categories satisfy that theorem. Rosicky showed [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/~rosicky/papers/brown4.pdf) that any combinatorial stable model category has a well generated homotopy category. This produces quite a bunch of examples, of additive nature though.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Are you referring to Theorem 8.3.3 in Neeman's Triangulated Categories?  It requires compact generatedness.

Comment: I take it that a functor $C \to Sets$, where $C$ is an $\infty$-category, is said to be "representable" if it factors as $C \to Spaces \xrightarrow{\pi_0} Set$ where the functor $C \to Spaces$ is representable in the usual $\infty$-categorical sense?

Comment: @TimCampion: Yes.  Equivalently, the induced functor Ho(C)→Set is representable.

Comment: @FernandoMuro As I recall one of the relevant statements in the Rosicky paper you link to had to be retracted -- I think he claims that $Ho(Ind_\lambda(K)) \to Ind_\lambda(Ho(K))$ is full for large $\lambda$ or something like that, and that this is not so. But I might be thinking of another paper...

Comment: [Here's](http://132.248.17.170/journals/TAC/volumes/20/2/20-02.pdf) the erratum I'm thinking of. He corrects statements and proofs, referring to conditions G1 - G4 which I couldn't find in the version Fernando links to, but which appear in the [journal version](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/14/19/14-19abs.html), Def 3.3. I believe conditions G1-G4 (which are dependent on a cardinal parameter $\lambda$) can always be satisfied for sufficiently large $\lambda$ in a combinatorial model category, and they guarantee $\lambda$-Brown representability. Conclude by Dugger's theorem.

Comment: @TimCampion I have linked to a correct version of Rosicky's paper from his site. The result I mention is there. The one you mention, if true, would be relevant for the other Brown representability theorem but we know many counterexamples by now.

Comment: The obvious candidate for the representing object is colim D, where D is the Grothendieck construction of F. Should be possible to check that it works by restricting checking to presentable objects only.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Proposition 8.4.2

Answer (score 10):

The theorem is, in fact, false even for finitely locally presentable $\infty$-categories, and indeed for the $\infty$-category of spaces, as has been known since Heller's paper

- *On the Representability of Homotopy Functors*, Journal of the London Mathematical Society (2) **23** (1981) pp. 551-562, doi:[10.1112/jlms/s2-23.3.551](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-23.3.551).

Heller's counterexample relies on the existence of a group admitting a unique conjugacy class of injections from every group in any given small set; of course no such group exists handling all groups at once.

The basic problem is that the homotopy category of spaces has no small set of objects detecting isomorphisms, a critical ingredient in Brown's original work as well as all its more specialized successors. (You need a small set of types of cells to construct your representing complex out of.) Arguably, the whole historical focus of algebraic topology (and of the study of Brown representability in particular) on pointed connected spaces, which are $\infty$-categorically not the objects of interest at all, comes down to the need to have a set of objects, in this case the spheres, detecting isomorphisms.

As for your question, your formulation is more complex than needed: the only $\alpha$-filtered colimits you care about are weak ones in the homotopy category that you'll use to build up your representing cell complex out of generators, so the correct hypothesis, as it has always been since Brown, is just the preservation of coproducts and weak pushouts in the homotopy category. But you'll need the generators to appear $\alpha$-compact with respect to these weak colimits, and if $\alpha$ is uncountable then your homotopy category does not admit such constructions, see my preprint *[Detecting isomorphisms in the homotopy category](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.04141)* with Christensen.

**EDIT:** Here is an explicit counterexample to the "only if" direction of the proposed theorem in a locally presentable $\infty$-category. (Note: there are no counterexamples to the "if" direction, but there are also no known examples of functors satisfying its hypotheses, even weakened to consider only sequences, with $\alpha$ uncountable.) Generally, it suffices to find an object $Z$ and an $\alpha$-indexed sequence $X_i$ together with a cocone under $(X_i)$ in the homotopy category with legs $f_i:X_i\to Z$ such that, for any choice of homotopies $H_{ij}:X_j\otimes \Delta^1\to Z$ between $f_i|_{X_j}$ and $f_j$, it is never possible to fill the induced maps $X_k\otimes \partial \Delta^1\to Z$ consisting of $H_{ik},H_{jk},$ and $H_{ij}|_{X_k}$. In this situation $(f_i)$ is a cocone in the homotopy category not inducing any map $\mathrm{colim} X_i\to Z$, which shows the functor represented by $Z$ does not send the $(\infty,1)$-colimit of the $\alpha$-indexed diagram $(X_i)$ to a weak colimit of sets.

The above framework is valid in any locally presentable $\infty$-category $\mathcal C$, and heuristically one should get counterexamples in essentially any such $\infty$-category and for essentially any choices of $Z$ and $(X_i)$. Franke's argument (introduction of *On the Brown representability theorem for triangulated categories*, Topology **40** (2001) pp.667-680, doi:[10.1016/S0040-9383(99)00034-8](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383%2899%2900034-8)) for this heuristic in the stable situation was as follows: There is a spectral sequence converging to $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(\mathrm{colim} X_i,Z)$ whose second page contains $\lim^q H^p(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X_i,Z))$, and the functor represented by $Z$ will only send $\mathrm{colim} X_i$ to a weak limit of sets if this spectral sequence collapses. Unfortunately, nobody seems to know how to compute these derived limits well enough to show that what intuitively ought to happen actually does happen-there are isolated explicit examples of ordinal-indexed sequences of abelian groups with nontrivial derived limits, but I don't know how to cook one into this spectral sequence.

So the only place I know how to follow the recipe above is in unpointed spaces, and indeed in the homotopy category of groupoids, where I can compute stuff directly. Christensen and I analyze an appropriate space $Z$ in section 3.3 of our preprint. The idea is to start with $(X_i)$ itself, then construct $Z$ as a kind of unfinished homotopy colimit that has an incoherent family of homotopies between its canonical maps from the $X_i$. The utility of working with groupoids here is that one can combinatorially show that such a cocone, with intuitively shouldn't cohere into a map from $\mathrm{colim} X_i$, actually does not. In particular, this construction uses properties of the homotopy category of spaces that are totally orthogonal to the lack of generating cogroups, so should make one more confident that the expected phenomena would appear in the stable situation if we could wrangle the spectral sequence.

While the $\alpha$-filtered colimit idea does not work, Brown representability can be proved efficiently for these categories. Use the fact that an $\alpha$-presentable $\infty$-category is reflective in a finitely presentable one, and steal Brown representability from there--it's easy to prove that a reflective subcategory of a category on which every functor preserving coproducts and weak pushouts is representable enjoys the same properties. When the resulting finitely presentable $\infty$-category is generated by a set of compact cogroups, you win. Unfortunately, as discussed above, the homotopy categories of finitely presentable $\infty$-categories do not usually have Brown representability available to steal. There is a way out: the spheres *do* detect isomorphisms in the homotopy **2-category** of the $\infty$-category of spaces, and from there it follows that the whole Brown representability story goes through perfectly for all $\alpha$-presentable $\infty$-categories--the only cost is that you have to take functors valued in groupoids, not in sets. Your mileage may vary on how "citeable" this is, but see 5.3.6 in my 2020 thesis, *[2-categorical Brown representability and the relation between derivators and $\infty$-categories](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/6834c18d)*.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, @DavidRoberts.

Comment: Just thinking out loud in case I'm missing something: this apparently means that there are at least 2 meanings of "abstract Brown representability" in the literature -- the direct generalization of the usual statement on the one hand, and Rosicky's version on the other hand. The former is false in general (but true for certain categories -- perhaps stably for instance?), and the latter is true.

Comment: I was aware of the unpointed counterexamples when I wrote the question, e.g., the work of Heller and also your work with Christensen.  What I don't understand, though, is your claim that these are counterexamples to Theorem 1.4.1.2 in Lurie's Higher Algebra (or Jardine's version).  Indeed, the very requirement of the existence of a cogroup structure on generators seems to immediately exclude all of your counterexamples.

Comment: @TimCampion: Given the continuous confusion as to what exact formulation is being meant, I added a precise statement to the original post.  (I did give a precise reference to Lurie, but apparently it wasn't enough.)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov No, I didn't (mean to) claim these are counterexamples to Lurie, Jardine, Neeman, or anybody. That was my point in the sentence "Arguably, the whole focus..." They're counterexamples to a literal reading of what you wanted, though, since you didn't ask for any pointedness etc in your categories. You can get an $\alpha$-version of Brown in the pointed world as a corollary to Lurie's version, or what have you, by the same argument I gave that applies in the unpointed world.

Comment: @TimCampion Rosicky's version relies on Neeman's theorem for well-generated triangulateds, which is the only proof of any kind of $\alpha$-Brown representability I'm aware of that doesn't use an embedding in something finitely presentable a la my argument above. So, yes, I'd say there is Brown's theorem, though I wouldn't say it's false in general but rather that not every homotopy 1-category satisfies its assumptions, and Neeman's theorem, and they aren't directly comparable.

Comment: "since you didn't ask for any pointedness etc in your categories": I did ask for it when I said "satisfying certain conditions" in the first paragraph and then referenced Theorem 1.4.1.2 in Lurie's Higher Algebra.  I guess this should have been made more explicit, though, so an explicit statement now appears in the main post.

Comment: Moving on to mathematics, in your third paragraph you seem to imply that any functor of the type discussed in the main post that sends coproducts to products and (∞,1)-pushouts to weak pullbacks also sends α-filtered (∞,1)-colimits to weak α-cofiltered limits?  How can one see this and is there a reference for such a statement?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov No, I don't claim that--the third paragraph is describing how you might try to prove a statement along your lines, and that such an approach won't work because weak $\alpha$-filtered colimits in the homotopy category behave badly. In fact, $\alpha$-filtered $(\infty,1)$-colimits don't need to be respected at all by functors to sets (or groupoids) which respect coproducts and $(\infty,1)$-pushouts. In particular, they have too many coherence conditions to become even weak colimits in the homotopy category.

Comment: Sorry for missing your intent with the question. The bolded question suggested to me quite strongly that you weren't interested in restricting to the special case of cogroup generators.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that the relevant case of α-filtered colimits here is colimits indexed by ordinals, since this is precisely what we need for transfinite compositions.  Does your observation also apply to (∞,1)-colimits indexed by ordinals?  The specific construction I have in mind would work like in Lurie's proof, but would use transfinite induction, and the passage to limit ordinals would be achieved by invoking the property about α-indexed (∞,1)-colimits mapping to weak limits.  (Which part of your paper with Christensen addresses this issue, by the way?)

Comment: To add to the previous comment, I just realized that my formulation really meant filtered (or ordinal-indexed) colimits in the (∞,1)-category C, not in its homotopy category Ho(C).  I clarified this aspect in the main post.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Yes, the problem appears already with ordinal-indexed colimits. Your construction works fine if your assumptions are satisfied, it’s just that they’re never satisfied—colimits indexed by $\alpha$ will never be sent to weak limits in Set. You can see this easily by considering a representable functor: it would say that a naively homotopy commutative cone under an $\alpha$-indexed diagram should always cohere into some map from the colimit, which is obstructed by (in the stable situation, at least) the derived functors of lim.

Comment: Dan and I address the natural next question: given that the colimits from the model won’t work, are there any choices at all of weak colimits in the homotopy category that might serve for the inductive step in the representability proof? We give a diagram for which no weak colimit thinks finite complexes are compact, which shows that this attempt to salvage the construction also fails.

Comment: @KevinArlin: Yes, that's what I mentioned in my previous comment, filtered colimits in Ho(C) are different from filtered (∞,1)-colimits in C.  However, it seems that from a practical perspective, it is (∞,1)-colimits that matter for the formulation of the Brown representability theorem; in particular, Lurie's formulation says that certain types of (∞,1)-colimits in C map to weak limits in Set, and my proposed formulation extends Lurie's statement by adding another type of an (∞,1)-colimit, namely, ordinal-indexed (∞,1)-colimits.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Everything I said two of my comments ago was in reference to the $(\infty,1)$-colimits. Those indexed by uncountable ordinals are simply not sent to weak limits by representable or potentially representable functors into sets.

Comment: @KevinArlin: Sorry, I misunderstood your last comment.  This sounds like a potential counterexample to the proposed formulation in the main post.  Do you have a simple example that would show this?  (Preferably for (∞,1)-categories satisfying the assumptions in the main post, e.g., locally presentable stable (∞,1)-categories?)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Sure, though unfortunately I don't think I can do stable. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is all quite instructive and I did not expect the counterexample for α-filtered colimits to be so complicated.  Just to confirm, does the new version imply the desired representability statement for any locally α-presentable (∞,1)-category with a generating set of α-compact cogroups?  The part that is not entirely obvious to me is whether any such category is a reflective localization of a locally finitely presentable category with a generating set of compact cogroups, i.e., whether we can choose localizations so that a generating set of compact cogroups exists.

Comment: No worries. I added the doi link for your latest edit (it doesn't turn up on the first page of a google search for me, so perhaps Elsevier is not trying to SEO _Topology_ so much, now it's not a current journal and everything in it can be read for free)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I quite agree that the gap between the basic intuition and the explicit counterexample is unexpectedly large. I remain hopeful there’s some way to make this all much easier. As for your question, no, I don’t claim that you can promote the cogroup generators from the $\alpha$-presentable to the finitely presentable $\infty$-category. But I don’t know for sure that you can’t.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I was wondering about that! I just use the copy from Ravenel’s site, but thanks for being less lazy than me.

Comment: @Kevin your thesis link has rotted! I wanted to add a link to it under your recent answer about derivator axioms, and searching led me here... I found the Wayback machine had a copy, so I popped the link to it in.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for spotting that! I've replaced the target with UCLA's official repository, which I assume will be there indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

(The following doesn't address the precise version of Brown representability asked about in the question body, but it does address *some* version of the title question, so I think for searchability it should be useful to mention it here.)

In Prop 2.15 of [Adams spectral sequences and Franke's algebraicity conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.03669), Patchkoria and Pstragowski prove the following:

**Thm (Patchkoria and Pstragowski):** Let $C$ be a presentable stable $\infty$-category and let $E : C^{op} \to  Ab$ be a homological functor which takes arbitrary direct sums in C to products of abelian groups. Then, $E$ is representable in the homotopy category $hC$.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out to me by George Raptis, a detailed treatment of Brown representability for $(n,1)$-categories ($1≤n≤∞$), stable or not, is now available in

- Hoang Kim Nguyen, George Raptis, Christoph Schrade.  [Higher Weak (Co)Limits, Adjoint Functor Theorems, and Higher Brown Representability](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.06003).  [doi:10.25537/dm.2022v27.1369-1420](https://doi.org/10.25537/dm.2022v27.1369-1420).  Documenta Mathematica 27 (2022), 1369–1420.

In particular, the article shows in Corollary 4.3.2 that the homotopy $n$-category of a presentable (∞,1)-category satisfies Brown representability if $2≤n≤∞$, and the homotopy $n$-category of a presentable stable (∞,1)-category satisfies Brown representability if $1≤n≤∞$.  The exclusion of $n=1$ in the unstable case is necessitated by the counterexamples of Heller and Arlin–Christensen discussed in the other answers.

In connection with this, Definition 4.2.7 introduces a notion of a compactly generated $n$-category and shows (Example 4.2.9) that the homotopy $n$-category of a finitely presentable (∞,1)-category is compactly generated if $n≥2$, whereas (Example 4.2.10) the homotopy $n$-category of a finitely presentable stable (∞,1)-category is compactly generated if $n≥1$.